# Firebreath 1.7 samples not working on Mac OS X Version 10.8.2

Tags: macos, firebreath

I'm trying to run examples on Mac 10.8.2 using XCode Version 4.6.2. It builds successfully, but the browser is not able to detect the plugin after I create the symlinks.
This is true for all browsers. None of them is able to detect either of the plugin(BasicMediaPlayer or FBTestPlugin. I tried different build options in XCode but no success.
Though the plugin built on Mac 10.8.2 worked on 10.7.5 after I copied the built plugin to its plugin folder. I'm not able to understand the problem. The samples built using
Firebreath 1.6 works perfectly fine on all systems.

Comment: Have you fixed this? If not, have you checked to make sure that the actual binary is generated inside the bundle?

Comment: No, I din't. Presently I'm using Firebreath 1.6 which shows no such problem. Sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 2):

with firebreath 1.7, the plugin generated was wrongly named as npFBTestPlugin.plugin

the correct name should be FBTestPlugin.plugin